# Is there native function to automatically put specific number of zeros based on actual and maximal value?

Tags: php, function

Is there any native PHP function which would allow me to do this?

```
$number = functionName(1, 9999); // $number == 0001
$number = functionName(10, 99); // $number == 10
$number = functionName(10, 999); // $number == 010
```

If there isn't native function, is there any user-based function?

Comment: That code you posted is very confusing. However, the function you're looking for is sprintf().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo str_pad($value, strlen($max), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

for example

```
$value = 10;
$max = 999;
echo str_pad($value, strlen($max), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
// returns 010
```

See http://ideone.com/KPBV2 and [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str-pad)

Answer (score 2):

use str_pad its easy! here's the doc

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but you can write one easily using [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/str-pad) and its pad_type of `STR_PAD_LEFT`.

Answer (score 0):

There sure is: [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
<?php
    echo str_pad(33, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo str_pad(1, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo str_pad(1258, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo str_pad(89965, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
```